# Where are the source files on the Jquery.com website? I see no download link

Tags: jquery

**Where are the source files on the Jquery.com website? I see no download link**

I'm learning Jquery and I want to play with the examples.

On this page:

http://jqueryui.com/effect/

I can view the source, and JS files are CDN, but the .css file is local:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

How can I download the whole package with all files to experiment with that on my local machine?

Usually most Scripts on other sites have full zipped packages?

Comment: Its not a question to ask here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you want to download style.css

Comment: Hi Aslam, what is the URL? I tried http://jquery.com/style.css, not working and also http://jqueryui.com/effect/resources/demos/style.css

Comment: When a link or other resource has a `/` at the beginning of the path, that means the hostname (jqueryui.com in this case) goes before it. So you end up with this path: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css. Spoiler: the contents are underwhelming.

Comment: You can get the UI themes in the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Comment: Thank you ordonezalex, that's what I was looking for.  I got confused by jquery.com versus jqueryui.com , solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download source file from this url http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

You can search all cdn code of jquery
https://cdnjs.com